# Creating CSV within bash containing field which has commas

Tags: bash, csv, delimiter

Hoping someone can assist with this query. I am attempting to replicate a CSV output and everything is fine at the moment aside from one field data that I am attempting to insert.

One of the fields contains multiple sets of data which contain commas to separate them however they are in the same field.

Is there any way in bash to generate this CSV so it can actually provide a CSV output that acknowledges that that particular field has multiple entries delimited by commas and not attempt to add those entries into a different field.

Cheers

wingZero

Details:

Field1, **Field2**, Field3

Data1, **DATA2,DATA22,DATA222**, Data3

Comment: You would usually enclose the field that has commas in double quotes, like so: `Data1, "DATA2,DATA22,DATA222", Data3`. Would this work for you?

Comment: Hi @hellmar-becker, I have tried this however when opening the csv it is entering the data into the other fields. So for example DATA22 will then be in Field 3. When generating the data I am just doing the below within bash. ```echo Field1,Field2,Field3 > test.csv``` and then appending the data via ```echo Data1,"DATA2,DATA22,DATA222",Data3 >> test.csv```

Comment: Ah, that's because bash eats the quotes. You would need to escape them, for instance `echo Data1,\"DATA2,DATA22,DATA222\",Data3`

Comment: Hi, I tried that however it just seems to add spaces and removes the commas and adds quotes.```field1  field2  field3
Data1   "DATA2  DATA22  DATA222"  Data3```